# Adding new data to an existing saved NSMutableArray saved on an iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have an app that uses a saved file to load 2 pieces of data every time the App starts. Runs perfectly fine.  On the NEW version of my App, I want to add a Third piece of data.  However, I get this error when I run it:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 2 beyond bounds [0 .. 1]

Because when it reads the file on startup, it calls for a third piece of data when the existing saved file only contains two.

Here's my code:

```
int roundingSegment = 1;
```

and then:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

//---Check for existence of the Archive File on Startup-
NSFileManager *filemgr;
NSString *docsDir;
NSArray *dirPaths;
filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

// Get the documents directory
dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];

// Build the path to the data file
dataFilePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"data.archive"]];

// Check if the file already exists, and if so, loads the data
if ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath:dataFilePath]) {
    NSMutableArray *dataArray;
    dataArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:dataFilePath];
    defaultValueTextField.text = [dataArray objectAtIndex:0];
    segment = [[dataArray objectAtIndex:1] intValue];
       roundingSegment = [[dataArray objectAtIndex:2] intValue];
    NSLog(@" Segment is %d", segment);
       NSLog(@" RoundingSegment is %d", roundingSegment);
    }

[super viewDidLoad];
}
```

The problem occurs right at the end of the method because the existing NSMutableArray file with TWO pieces of data already exists and my code is trying to read a THIRD, namely the 'roundingSegment' variable.  (where I indented the code under // Check if the file exists...)

Do I have to delete the existing NSMutableArray the user has his data saved in when he loads the NEW version of the App?  And if so, HOW?!

OR, more preferably, is there a way to augment and add a third piece of data on the first run of the App so it doesn't hang when it tries to get my 'roundingSegment' variable?

Any help you can lend would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You need to check [dataArray count] to see how many elements are in your array.

You should also consider refactoring your code to use a better mechanism for storing app data. Take a look at `NSUserDefaults`.